# Find workspace of a particular job in Hudson CI

Tags: java, hudson

I am writing a Hudson CI plug-in.

Question: Is there any function which will give me the workspace for a particular job?
          I need to traverse this workspace to get the files in these workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getWorkspace%28%29

```
hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getWorkspace().toURI()
```

You should have a reference to `build` in most places this would be useful.